# Accessing a url of an opened window of MIGS

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window of MIGS (payment service of VISA and MasterCart) and access its URL, but I have an exception: "Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross frame".

my code:

```
var wind = window.open(myUrl);
setInterval(function(){
    var x = wind.location.href;
},6000)
```

How can I access any changes to the URL?

Comment: Why would `myUrl` not contain what you require?

Comment: because the url changes when the user enter his data and send to MIGS then MIGS send its response in URL which I need to read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: I try this before but it didn't work